# displaying .db file php

Tags: php, database, ftp

I have .db file which is SQLite format 3 and is in ftp server. I can simply open it with BD Browser for SQLite when I copy it to my PC. The question is how do I display it's data on my web? I made ftp connection:

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
        $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
        $info = "ftp://" . $ftp_username . ":" . $ftp_userpass . "@" . $ftp_server . "/path/to/file/data.db";
```

And now im lost. What's the next step?
To be more acurate I need to display specific database table. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to open a sqlite database located on another server using FTP? Why would you need to do that? And what is your question? How to work with SQLite in general?

Comment: it's just that I have .db file in my ftp server.  And possibly yes. How to work with SQLite maybe. I need to echo a normal table on my web

Comment: I would look for another db-solution for this. I don't even know if it is possible to do what you are trying and even if it is, it sounds like a really bad idea. Regarding working with SQLite in general, there are 1000's of tutorials for that. Ask Google. (If you use PDO, then it's basically the same as reading from any other DB vendor with PDO.)

Comment: that ftp server is game server and there are stats and all other.

Comment: Alrighty. I will take a look at that. Thanks !

Comment: Alright. I think I know what I need. I need to connect to .db with $db = new SQLite3('file.db'); but whenever I try to do that I get error Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to open database: unable to open database file. I googled it and found out that this may be a permission problem. Any ideas how do I change permissions?